# Use a custom cursor for "pointer"

Tags: css

Is it possible to, using only CSS, change the cursor of "pointer" to a custom one?

So that if I reference it like in:

```
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

html {
  cursor: url("/static/images/paw-cursor.svg"), pointer;
}
```

`pointer` will reference my custom cursor. Otherwise it will use the browser's default cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Use:

```
cursor: url(/static/images/paw-cursor.svg), auto;
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1majnh04/